# jQuery replacement for toggle()

Tags: jquery, toggle

It seems one of my `toggle()` functions have depreciated, I am just wondering what a suitable replacement would be. I have searched but can't seem to find a clear answer, can anyone help?

Here is my code

```
$( ".open-btn" ).toggle(function() {
    $(".foldable").css( "height", "517px" );
    $(".open-btn a").text( "CLOSE MENU" );
    $(".reserve-btn").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(".foldable").css( "height", "0px" );
    $(".open-btn a").text( "SHOW MENU" );
    $(".reserve-btn").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: You could simply apply a `click` handler to the element, and set the value of a `data-*` attribute to determine which one of the toggles to fire.

Comment: If you google _jquery toggle deprecated_, the first hit is the jQuery Forum thread: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function assignToggleHandler() {
    $(".open-btn a").click(function() {
        if($(".open-btn a").text() == "SHOW MENU") {
            $(".foldable").css( "height", "517px" );
            $(".reserve-btn").fadeIn();
            $(".open-btn a").text( "CLOSE MENU" );
        } else {
            $(".foldable").css( "height", "0px" );
            $(".open-btn a").text( "SHOW MENU" );
            $(".reserve-btn").fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Then just call the function:

```
assignToggleHandler();
```

PM me if you want an example of one I built in a page I'm building right now.

Comment: Why have you made a function that assigns an event handler?  It would make more sense to move the code outside the function and just dump the function completely.  That way it doesn't have to be called.

Comment: in case it has to be called throughout a script. All he has to do it call the function. If he is using several scripts, it can be called anytime he needs to on any page in any script. It is just an option for him. I'm not telling him he has to do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it for him, as that's not a normal way of doing things.  Maybe a more suitable function name would be better, like `assignToggleHandler` or something :)

Comment: agreed....edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$( ".open-btn" ).click(function() {
    $(".foldable").css('height') === '0 ? $(".foldable").css('height','517px') : $(".foldable").css('height', 0);
    $(".open-btn a").text(($('.open-btn a').text() == 'SHOW MENU') ? 'CLOSE MENU' : 'SHOW MENU');
    $(".reserve-btn").fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: This works except for the height on the .foldable, any ideas?

Comment: Try again with my update :-)